# PHP exec() SELinux commands

Tags: php, exec

My goal is to receive command "semanage login -l" message in array and display the results in the browser.
I have created a line inside a class Ausearch where it has a function processSudoInput() with contents:

```
  public function processSudoInput()
    {
       exec("echo password | /usr/bin/sudo -S semanage login -l ",$output);
       return $output;
    }
```

The problem is that when I print the $output in the terminal, I get nice results (an array with strings). Class ausearch is being called inside a separate .php file CommandHandler.php where it contains:

```
use Commands\Ausearch;

include 'Commands/Ausearch.php';

function displayLogData()
{
    $ausearch = new Ausearch();
    $result = $ausearch->processSudoInput();
    var_dump($result);
}
displayLogData();
```

When I execute this php code inside the PHPStorm I get results:

```
 [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(70) "Login Name           SELinux User         MLS/MCS Range        Service"
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
```

and it continues so on.
But when I call this function inside the browser (inside the HTML file) then it returns

```
array(0) { }
```

Inside the browser.
So far I have tried executing `visudo` and adding

```
%www-data ALL=NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Even tried to `chown -R apache:apache /var/www`
and `chown -R 777 /var/www`
and no luck.
Even set selinux to permissive
Currently using CentOS8 and the target is to achieve an array with data as above inside the browser at all costs, no matter the security.

Comment: Randomly copying and pasting things from the internet is unlikely to solve your problem, and more likely to compromise or wreck your system. If you've set `NOPASSWD` in your sudoers file, why are you piping a password to the `sudo` command? Why does your sudoers file refer to `www-data` but you later refer to the user `apache`? Is `semanage` in your path? Have you tried using the third parameter to `exec()` to give you a better idea of what the problem is?

Comment: You have a great point, after posting this question I've come to the conclusion that `www-data` is not the user anymore, it was apache. Also, I've made shell scripts where those commands are encapsulated and later executed in code `exec(sudo /path/to/shell)` , I need `exec()` function return type value (do not need `shell_exec` ). And later in the sudoers file, I gave `NOPASSWD` access to that file and everything worked. In conclusion, do not write code at 3 am for your thesis experiments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On CentOS8 distro and other distros which use `httpd` process there is no such system subject (user) `www-data` nor `httpd`. When executing sudo commands in the "PHPStorm" there is user A and he has all the needed permissions to execute those commands, although when it comes to executing sudo commands and displaying them on the web, the user B is responsible for it and that user B is `Apache`, therefore if it is needed to run that command, it is highly suggestible to create shell script which executes that specific sudo command aka encapsulating that command. Inside the `visudo` there has to be a line:

```
%apache ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/shell/file.sh
```

In many internet examples, there are no mentions of `%apache` component (as far I was searching). Shell file is suggestible so to avoid using which is a huge security flaw (above solution neither is a good solution aka not great no terrible)

```
%apache ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

After adding line above in the `visudo` then there is possible to run line in the PHP

```
exec('sudo /path/to/shell/file.sh`, $output)
```

or

```
shell_exec('sudo /path/to/shell/file.sh')
```

Depending on your goals

Important to mention, that `sudo` is a requirement in those functions to execute those scripts.